# The Square Root of a Positive Irrational is Irrational

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

$(\forall x ∈ I^+)[\sqrt{x} ∈ I]$ where $I^+$ represents the domain of all positive irrational numbers.

It makes sense to me intuitively that the square root of any irrational number is bound to be an irrational but I don't know how to go about writing it as a universal generalization proof.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose it is not true. So there is positive $o$ irrational so that $\sqrt{o}$  is rational. Squaring we get $\sqrt{o}^2=o$ is rational. Woops.

Comment: Using $i$ for an irrational number is a bit confusing...

Comment: Good point, I changed it for $o$. thanks.

Comment: @TrevorRichards: Do you use $i$ for indices for summation or sequences? How about $e$ for identity in a group? Or $π$ for prime counting function or permutations or projections?

Answer (score 2):

This is true.  Suppose that $x$ is rational.  Then $x=m/n$ for some integers $m$ and $n$.  Therefore $x^2=m^2/n^2$ is rational, and is thus not in $I+$.  Turning this around, if $x\in I+$, $\sqrt{x}$ cannot be rational, so $\sqrt{x}\in I+$.

Answer (score 2):

You can rephrase what you're trying to prove as:

> If $x$ is irrational, so is $\sqrt{x}$.

Or, substituting $y=\sqrt{x}$ gives:

> If $y^2$ is irrational, so is $y$.

Or, taking the contrapositive:

> If $y$ is rational, so is $y^2$.

This statement is equivalent to the original. Can you prove it?